# Link conventions

Tags: coding-style, markdown, code-structure

There are multiple ways of declaring a link with a title or without. I'm wondering whether there is a preferred way of doing it, either official or widely used in the community.

Taken from [markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#formatting-the-second-part-of-the-link](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#formatting-the-second-part-of-the-link), here are all the ways of declaring reference-style links (this also applies to inline-style links, there would just be a `(` instead of `:`  and a `)` at the end):

```
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbit#Lifestyle
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbit#Lifestyle "Hobbit lifestyles"
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbit#Lifestyle 'Hobbit lifestyles'
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbit#Lifestyle (Hobbit lifestyles)
[1]: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbit#Lifestyle> "Hobbit lifestyles"
[1]: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbit#Lifestyle> 'Hobbit lifestyles'
[1]: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbit#Lifestyle> (Hobbit lifestyles)
```

I assume the whitespace after `[1]:` should be included, considering they haven't shown this option. Is that correct?

I've looked at the official documentation by John Gruber at [daringfireball.net/projects/markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown) and it looks like they prefer `[name]: link "title"`.

If there's not a "preferred" way, which one do you use and why? Are any of them functionally different in any way whatsoever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White space after `[1]:` should be included it even says so in [Formatting the Second Part of the Link](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#formatting-the-second-part-of-the-link): "The label, in brackets, followed immediately by a colon and **at least one space**"

My preferred style is `[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbit#Lifestyle "Hobbit lifestyles"`. I try to avoid single quotes and brackets.